# Android - how to only show(or able to select) files with a custom extension when calling "file selector" using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter, file-extension

I know that you can restrict available file types showing up in a file explorer called by [**Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) easily by using [setType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)), but that can only work for the known file extensions like .jpg, .pdf, .docx, what I need is to only show the files that have a **custom extension**, like .abc, so the user can only select a file that ends with .abc. I've searched for a long time and still can't find an effective way to solve this; the closest one is to create a custom mime type, like this:

```
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/customtype" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/customtype" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/customtype"); 
startActivityForResult(intent,FILE_SELECTOR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

to show the file selector, but this results with no files extensions available at all, no files can be selected :( I really can't think of another way to only show files with custom extensions, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: not really, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of **data android:mimeType="application/customtype"**, you should use **data android:mimeType="*/*"**.  That will catch all mime types that the OS on your device supports.  You simply cannot define custom types which the OS doesn't know about.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I've seen some apps that can only show custom types of files in the system file explorer.

Comment: @jackz314 Absolutely sure.  Try an app like JSON Tool (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vibo.jsontool&hl=en), you will see that it shows up as the chooser for all kinds of files on the OS.

Comment: ok, guess I'll have to go with that or build a customized one, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @jackz314, did you find any solution?, I saw this table, it will help to open custom file only, there is table there to see http://indyvision.net/android-snippets/android-using-intents-open-files/

Comment: I didn't find any solution, I just went with allowing all types and notify the user if the extension isn't the one used in my app. The table you provided only know extensions, not what I needed but thanks anyways.