# How to only show files with custom extension in file chooser on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

I've seen the same question posted here: [Android - how to only show(or able to select) files with a custom extension when calling "file selector" using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519004/android-how-to-only-showor-able-to-select-files-with-a-custom-extension-when) but they did not manage to solve it.

I want to force the user to pick a file with a custom extension .xyz from the file chooser. The intent is created something like this:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = <what goes here?>
```

Is that possible to do?

If not, is there any alternative - like searching through the external storage to find all files with that file ending and return the data (collection of files) in the same manner an intent would do?

Comment: "Is that possible to do?" -- no, sorry. "If not, is there any alternative - like searching through the external storage to find all files with that file ending and return the data (collection of files) in the same manner an intent would do?" -- you could do that, bearing in mind that your app does not have direct filesystem access to all of external storage on Android 10 and higher, and assuming that you only need read access for those files.

Comment: You can find all MIME types [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, thank you for the reply. Would you mind linking some information about the file system access on Android 10?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage?hl=en#scoped-storage